# Taking average of dataframe elements sharing same date

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a bit lost in how to take average of a data frame formatted in the following way:

```
id  date        quantity    product
1   12-05-2015  10          apple
2   21-03-2015  12          orange
3   12-05-2015  15          orange
4   21-03-2015  16          apple
```

Expected result:

```
date       quantity
21-03-2015 14
12-05-2015 12.5
```

I tried converting it to zoo object, but then I run into issues as dates are non-unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
aggregate(quantity~date, df1, mean)
#        date quantity
#1 12-05-2015     12.5
#2 21-03-2015     14.0
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(quantity=mean(quantity)), date]
```

As @Alex A. mentioned in the comments, `list(` can be replaced by `.(` in the recent data.table versions.

Comment: you must be typing dplyr solution now :D

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar: I am!

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar  No, I left it for you :-)

Comment: Seems a little more "data.table-ish" to use `.()` rather than `list()`, at least IMO. Nice solution! :)

Comment: @AlexA.  Thanks, I think the `.(` option became available in the recent versions,

Comment: beautiful aggregate solution, thank you. Accepting as soon as timer passes.

Comment: @LucasSeveryn  Thanks for your generous comment

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `dplyr` package. Assuming your data frame is called `df`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarize(quantity = mean(quantity))

#         date quantity
# 1 12-05-2015     12.5
# 2 21-03-2015     14.0
```

This gets the mean quantity grouped by date.